# func_get_args and foreach

Tags: php

what's different between this two,
why when I use func_get_args
foreach only echo last number "7"

```
function add(){
    $total=func_get_args();
    foreach($total as $result);
    echo $result;
    }

add(1, 5 , 6, 7);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$array=array(1, 5, 6, 7);
foreach($array as $result){
    echo $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start you are doing nothing with the foreach loop

```
foreach ($total as $result) /* nothing */ ;
```

What's happening is the last `$result` is left and is echo'd by the next line.

You could actually rewrite the add function like so:

```
function add(){
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}

echo add(1, 5 , 6, 7);
```

Which is cooler imho ;) (but doesn't check for string values and such)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon from

```
foreach($total as $result);
```

It should be

```
foreach($total as $result)
```